# how to make sure only one bashoperator is retried but not other airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have dag file as follows. Here I have no retries. However, I want to make sure particular files ( bash1, bash2) is should have retries 1. but not others file.

Following is default arguments.

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2017, 3, 24, 19, 00),
    'email': ['myemail@email.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'backfill': False,
}
```

I define dag as following:
    dag = DAG('x', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval = "15 0,1,2,3,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 * * *")

My first Operator is define like following:

```
bash1 = BashOperator(
        task_id= 'bash1',
        bash_command="cd /home/ubuntu/run_scripts/Test/inst/scripts && /usr/bin/Rscript bash1.R ",
        dag=dag
    )
```

My Second Operator is define like following:

```
bash2 = BashOperator(
        task_id= 'bash2',
        bash_command="cd /home/ubuntu/run_scripts/Test/inst/scripts && /usr/bin/Rscript bash2.R ",
        dag=dag
    )
```

My final Operator is define like following:

```
Test_join = BashOperator(
        task_id= 'Test_join',
        bash_command="cd /home/ubuntu/run_scripts/Test/inst/scripts && /usr/bin/Rscript Test_join.R ",
        dag=dag
    )
```

Test_join depends upon bash1 and bash 2.

```
Test_join.set_upstream(bash1)
Test_join.set_upstream(bash2)
```

What should I have to do to make sure bash1 and bash2 retired 2 but not Test_join.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameter 'retries' while declaring a task.